# mySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I've been making a quiz on php and mysql...

I've used the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to keep track of the time that users answer on specific questions. Now I would like to print out the time, and I've made a row in my database called 'timestamp'.

It works perfectly to track which users answered first, but when i echo out the row, it looks like this:

```
2012-01-11 17:14:50
```

So my question is:

How do I break this up in time and date?

I can't have 2 rows in my database for storing the time, cause as I said I use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to track which users answered first.

The way it's printed out now isn't very nice to look at, and it's not very flexible to work with.

Hope anybody can help out,

Thanks alot for reading.

Mathias.

Comment: Try `echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($yourVariable) );` Sorry, I put in the US date format, don't know where you are, but you can create your own mask by looking here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: might want to add ms to the time if you use it to determine who answered first.

Comment: Why would you ever want to break up the date and time?  They're both essential for determining actually when something happened, and I have never seen a good reason for storing them separately.  If you simply want to display them separately, do that instead.  The database is for data storage.  Formatting and what not should be handled by your application, generally speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the datetime formatted in an aesthetically pleasing way.  Check out this website: http://www.mysqlformatdate.com/ for all sorts of formats and find what you like best and add it to your select statement.

Comment: I'd go with the MySQL documentation over that site.

Comment: As would I, but it is apparent that the author is new and MySQL's documentation ( or any of the RDBMS's documentation for that matter ) can be pretty daunting.  The site will help them see what the different format mask's do and how to use them, and give them sample sql to show them how to use it in select statements.  That is the reason I recommended it for the Author.

Comment: This site really helped! I've got no problem using it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

have a read through http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
    <?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-01-11 17:14:50');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format it any way you like using MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), or you can use PHP's [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function to convert it to a Unix timestamp and subsequently use the [`date`](http://php.net/date) function on it.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```

or:

```
print date('l F Y', strtotime('2009-10-04 22:23:00'));
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like to get the unix timestamp from MYSQL so in your sql query do:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as time FROM table
```

where `time` is the column name then in php:

```
$in_format_time = date("H:i d M Y T",$time);
echo $in_format_time;
```

where `$time` was the fetched result. This will output the following:   19:00 01 Jan 1970 GMT.

But you can play with the format you like in the date function, take a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W, %M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p')`

`yields 'Sunday, September 20, 2008 @ 12:45 PM'`

```
MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Letter Representations
Specifier   Description
%a          Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)
%b          Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%c          Month, numeric (0..12)
%D          Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
%d          Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%e          Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
%f          Microseconds (000000..999999)
%H          Hour (00..23)
%h      Hour (01..12)
%I      Hour (01..12)
%i      Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%j      Day of year (001..366)
%k      Hour (0..23)
%l      Hour (1..12)
%M      Month name (January..December)
%m      Month, numeric (00..12)
%p      AM or PM
%r      Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
%S      Seconds (00..59)
%s      Seconds (00..59)
%T      Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%U      Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week
%u      Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week
%V      Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; used with %X
%v      Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; used with %x
%W      Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
%w      Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
%X      Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V
%x      Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v
%Y      Year, numeric, four digits
%y      Year, numeric (two digits)
%%      A literal “%” character
%x          x, for any “x” not listed above
```